# if [ -e $name ]; what -e does?

Tags: bash, scripts

Someone could helps me saying me what -e does within an if construct an followed by a directory or file? thanks very much

Answer (score 5):

See `man test` for details. `-e` returns true if the file or directory exists, and false if it doesn't.

Comment: Or if you feel like it: man [